# Remove item without swap in Realm

Tags: swift, realm

If I use this code:

```
try! self.realm.write {

                    let deletedObject = self.storage_array[lbl.tag]
                    self.realm.delete(deletedObject)

                    self.reload()
                    }
```

where

```
let realm = try! Realm()
    lazy var storage_array: Results<Storage> = { self.realm.objects(Storage) }()
```

The item is removed but at this place the last item is appeared.
That is, before: 1,2,3,4, (remove 2) after: 1,4,3

How can I remove this item without changing the arrangement? That is, I want: 1,3,4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects in a Realm have no inherent order. If you'd like the objects in a `Results` to be in a specific order you should sort them explicitly using [`Results.sorted(_:ascending:)`](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Results.html#/s:FC10RealmSwift7Results6sortedFTSS9ascendingSb_GS0_x_).